# Retrieving every 5th character from a file using a for loop only, no readlines

Tags: python

So here is the following problem that I need to do for this class, I could do it easily but we are not allowed to use readline or read, only a for loop:

> b.    Write a program that takes two filenames from a user – one for
>   input (we will use poem.txt and suess.txt as test files) and one for
>   output. Then the program reads the specified input file and creates
>   the new output file that contains every fifth character from the input
>   file only if that character is a letter. In addition, the character
>   should be uppercase if it is a vowel, and lowercase if it is a
>   consonant. Finally, the program should output statistics for the
>   altered text, including:
>
> • The number of characters •  The number of consonants •  The number of
>   vowels
>
> For example, if the input file contains:
>
> ```
> Do you like green eggs and ham? I like them, Sam I am! Do you like
> green eggs and ham, Sam? Do you like them, Sam I am?
> ```
>
> then the output file should be: OkEgnmltIOkEgnmmltI
>
> The number of characters: 
>   19 The number of consonants: 13 The number of vowels: 6

Here's what I got so far (ignore file placeholders):

```
#init vars
vowels = 'aeiou'
cons = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
noVowels = 0
noCons = 0
noChars = 0
i = 0

#Get input and output files
#usrIn = input("Input File: ")
#usrOut = input("Output File: ")

#File Manage
fi = open('suess.txt', 'r')
fo = open('test.txt', 'w')

#For loop
for line in fi:
    if (line[i+4].lower() in vowels):
        noVowels += 1
        fo.write(line[i+4].upper())
    elif (line[i+4].lower() in cons):
        noCons += 1
        fo.write(line[i+4].lower())




#Output stats    
noChars = noCons + noVowels
print("The number of characters: {}".format(noChars))
print("The number of consonants: {}".format(noCons))
print("The number of vowels: {}".format(noVowels))

#close files
fi.close()
fo.close()
```

I've tried messing around with incrementing 'i' but it produces false output, which I guess is because it is only increasing 'i' after the line is already read, which obviously is wrong. I need it to get every 5th char in the line, and then start over at the 5th character for next line.
Please Help!

Comment: It is a best practice to open a file with a `with` statement, that way, the file is automatically closed for you. See [PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range function with for loop:

```
text = "Do you like green eggs and ham? I like them, Sam I am! Do you like green eggs and ham, Sam? Do you like them, Sam I am?"
transform = ''

for l in range(4, len(text), 5):
    transform += text[l]

#remove spaces (as your example).
transform = transform.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: We can't use any libraries like 're' so that is out of the question

Comment: this is just an additif to complete proposition. Edited ;)

Comment: good enough for me that worked great. Idk why they don't want us to use libraries or simple functions, but hey whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
info = {
    'vowels': 'aeiou',
    'cons': 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz',
    'noVowels': 0,
    'noCons': 0,
    'noChars': 0
}

with open("suess.txt", 'r') as fh:
    text = list(''.join([l for l in fh]))

output = ''
for k, v in enumerate(text):
    if ((k+1) % 5) == 0 and v.lower() in info['vowels'] + info['cons']:
        if v in info['cons']:
            info['noCons'] += 1
        else:
            info['noVowels'] += 1
            v = v.upper()

        output += v

fh.close()

print(output)
print("The number of characters: {}".format(info['noCons'] + info['noVowels']))
print("The number of consonants: {}".format(info['noCons']))
print("The number of vowels: {}".format(info['noVowels']))
```

The output:

```
OkEgnmltIOkEgnmmltI
The number of characters: 19
The number of consonants: 13
The number of vowels: 6
```